# Can we in the far future have an energy source made from vacuum energy, antimatter, dark energy, Higgs boson?

Tags: energy, energy-conservation, antimatter, higgs, dark-energy

Can we in the far future have an energy source made from vacuum energy, antimatter, dark energy, Higgs boson and all kind of these like stuffs?

Comment: I deleted a nonconstructive comment discussion. Everyone please keep in mind that comments are meant for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification.

Comment: @DavidZ then where i can discuss this matter?

Comment: We have [chat] available for general discussion.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking us to predict the future and not about (mainstream) physics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @userLTK Higgs boson is a particle that give mass to other particles
>   ,so why can't it be used for an energy source hypothetically

Too long for a comment, so I'll put here.

In simple terms, energy is like a staircase, if you're on a higher step, you can take a step down and get available energy, but if you're on the bottom step, you can't go anywhere lower.  Available or accessible energy is like squeezing water form a sponge, it only works if there's already water in the sponge.  You can squeeze a dry sponge forever and get no water.

Quantum states tend towards the bottom of the staircase naturally, so available energy isn't there with most stable particles.   That's why the Higgs or Dark matter or Dark Energy probably aren't good energy sources because they are already as low as they can go.    Until we learn precisely what Dark Energy and Dark Matter are we can't say for sure, but they are probably already at the bottom of the stairs.

Hydrogen is different and rather cool in this sense because it's stable but it's not at the bottom of the staircase.  It has more energy than things you can make from hydrogen, which means, it's an available and abundant energy source.  If you squeeze hydrogen hard enough, but you need to squeeze it as hard as the core of a star, then it turns into Helium and releases energy.   The Higgs, Dark Matter, Dark Energy - probably not the case with them.

In fact, it takes enormous amounts of energy just to create 1 measurable Higgs particle.  They're very elusive and probably useless as an energy source.

Now if you want to talk super-duper hypothetical, maybe there are methods by which quantum fields can be manipulated and gravity or mass can be turned on or off by methods we don't currently understand.  If that's possible (and I'm guessing it's not), but if it is, then there might be virtually free energy generation, but I find that idea improbable.

Black holes are also, curiously, a potential energy source, cause you can take a lump of rock, pretty useless as an energy source, and drop it into a black hole and in falling in and forming an accretion disk, the matter will be compacted and get so hot before it reaches the black hole that jets of gamma rays and streams of particles and anti particles that can be harnessed as an energy source would shoot outwards, coming from the energy of the object you dropped in.   That would be enormously difficult to do from an engineering standpoint, but the energy availability is there, but its also probably not necessary.   Hydrogen is so abundant, that's fusion is probably all we'll ever need.

Comment: What about tachyons?

Comment: @NihalJalaluddinP   Lets wait until somebody discovers one, then we can ask that question.

Comment: I didn't get how energy is related to  turning on or off the gravity or mass.

Comment: That was a bit vague of me.  If, in theory, gravitation can be generated like magnetism, then it can run a piston and generate electricity using manipulated gravitation, but there's no indication that's even possible.    It wasn't a good example on my part.

Comment: Come on,I wants energy source which will change these turbine and all.

Comment: Well if electrons can be used as electricity what about gravitons as graviticity 

Comment: Sorry about the grammar.i was in a hurry.